# C# get filenames using a directory

Tags: c#, ssis, io

I have a path "C:\Desktop\Testing" with multiple files e.g "abc.txt";"def.txt",

I want to display path + filename as string. Code is something like this

```
           string path = @"C:\Desktop\Testing";
           string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(path);
           foreach (string file in fileList)
             {
              
              }     
           string fullPathName = path + file;
```

I need the fullPathName in order to create zip by addfile.CreateEntryFromFile(fullPathName, file)

Results for fullPathName should be C:\Desktop\Testing\abc.txt

Comment: Since `Directory.GetFiles` returns the full path and name, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified
> directory.

So I suppose that your loop could be

```
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    addfile.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Path.GetFileName will strip the path part and returns just the filename

Comment: I get an error using the below:  
string inputfilepath = @"C:\Desktop\Testing"
  string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(inputfilepath);
            foreach (string file in fileList)
            {        var fileStream = new FileStream(zipfile, FileMode.Create);
                    fileStream.Close(); 
            using (ZipArchive addfile = ZipFile.Open(zipfile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                    {
                        addfile.CreateEntryFromFile(inputfilepath, Path.GetFileName(file));
                    }
                    File.Delete(inputfilepath);
             }

Comment: Why do you put the creation of the zip file inside the loop? Also there is no need to open again and again the ZipFile. These actions should be external to the loop. And what is the error message?